# Sync fork with upstream repo without creating a PR commit

Tags: git, github

When I start working on a new feature on a repo and I have an existing fork, I need to create a PR to sync my fork with the upstream repo. When I merge it into my fork, it creates a commit, which says something like

> Merge pull request ... from master

When I fork a repo for the first time, I am able to get a fork without any new commits in it. So I am thinking that there should be a way for me to sync my repo without having to create an extra commit about the PR itself (other than whatever new change is already in upstream)

Is there a way to do it? If not, what is the rationale behind not being able to sync the repo through UI? (Just a feature that is not available?)

Answer (score -1):

Doing a rebase will not create the additional merge commit, so I think you can do

```
git pull --rebase <remote>
```